# How do I export model with shaders?

Tags: materials, node-editor, shaders, texture-baking

I have no texture image but colors and shading in materials. I want to export it in fbx so those materials(no image texture) with my shaders will be applied in the result. I'm absolutely new to shading and baking stuff so I would like you to explain it to me if you could. There's also a little bit of glitter on the material made by Voronoi texture just for the record. [image: Model in shading]

here's the .blend file of model [image]

Comment: other programs will use their own shading systems in most every case. You will need to remake your materials in your destination software, be it unity, unreal or other. See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures gltf format is the only possible exception where supported i think, but maybe not supported by all platforms.

Comment: Thank you for the useful information but I want to ask about baking texture, since its the way to export. There's a not small amount of different options for different textures. If you could explain to me what I should use for those materials I will appreciate that.

Answer (score 2):

If you want use this model in a new blender file, save the file with this model. Open the new blender file that you want to import it into. Select File then select append, navigate to the old file where your model is, double click on the file name and go into objects, select your model/object name and then press the append button and your object should be imported with the shaders that are assigned to it.

Comment: Thank you for answering but this is not what I meant. I want to export it in fbx format. So that when it will be loaded in other programs like unity it will look like this or at least close to this.

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood your question. You should edit your question adding that you would like to export it as fbx.

Comment: This link should help you out [link](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/import_export/node_shaders_info.html)

Comment: It looks like Principled BSDF is the main shader but I don't understand how to connect all other shaders to it the right way. Anyway thanks for trying to help.

Comment: Post your blend file using blend exchange in the link here. [link](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) I am sure other people who know better that me will help out.